# Convert int to char[]

Tags: arduino-mega, string, c-string

I'm looking to convert an int value to a char array. currently I've found the following will return `[number]`

```
int num = [number]
str = String(num);
str.toCharArray(cstr,16);
Serial.println(cstr);
```

However, per [Majenko's The Evils of Arduino Strings](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/) I feel like this code would make my Arduino's heap look like swiss cheese. Is there a better way to change an `[int]` into a `char[n]` array that avoids the **S**tring class?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`itoa` is the best route:

```
int num = 1234;
char cstr[16];
itoa(num, cstr, 10);
-> "1234"
```

You can read more about using it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/).

If you want more control over the format of the number (and don't mind the increased PROGMEM usage) you can use `sprintf` (or the more secure `snprintf`) to format it:

```
sprintf(cstr, "%05d", num);
-> "01234"
```

Or with PROGMEM string constant:

```
sprintf_P(cstr, (PGM_P)F("%05d"), num);
-> "01234"
```

Or with more values:

```
sprintf_P(cstr, (PGM_P)F("%02d:%02d:%02d"), hours, minutes, seconds);
-> "03:23:11"
```

Comment: Nice, I'm looking to take an int value in seconds and convert to hr:min:sec before I `strcat([c string],[time])` as I understand, I'll have to stick with `itoa` since I don't want it to go to serial?

Comment: sprintf is a good choice. I'll add an example.

Comment: Ok, that looks like it will work for me. how do you go about getting the `(PGM_P)F("%02d:%02d:%02d"),` section? (specifically the `(PGM_P)F` part)

Comment: The F is documented in the arduino PROGMEM docs. The PGM_P just changes the pointer to the right type for_P variant functions.

Comment: You can also use the PrintEX library to give you all the 'printf' capabilities without having to deal with string types.